# Pressing Alt key gives focus to menu bar overriding shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

*I started yesterday evening to have this problem, it never happened before.*

I am working with the Eclipse IDE and one of my shortcuts is Shift + Alt + F. I have always used it, until yesterday I noticed that it was not working anymore and instead the menu bar was activating.

I realized now that when I press Alt + F, the "File" menu in the menu bar gets selected and opened.

I understand it's a Windows thing, but why did it start happening only now? Is there a way to disable this annoying feature without using some remapper or utility?

I'm on W10 Anniversary and Eclipse Luna 4.4.2.

Comment: Is there anything that happened roughly the same time? Did you update windows or update Eclipse?

Comment: @LPChip No updates. Actually, it happened throughout the same session, at a random time. I tried to restart, see if I enabled some Key Lock or something, but no luck.